# Is it impractical to use GNU Radio without the Companion GUI?

Tags: gnuradio

I have a relatively new M1-based Macbook but Companion isn't stable. It will, for example, crash as soon I as I try to choose the "File" or "Edit" menus and has crashed while I was attempting to adjust parameters.

I am able to communicate with and obtain samples from my Ettus N210 just fine but I'd like to eventually try to use the DVB-S2 receive blocks.

This is all a bit new to me, but I'm an experienced Python programmer and don't mind if I have to write some code. I don't necessarily need a Qt application to be generated--I'm fine with wiring things up and writing data to a file.

Is it practical to do this? Can someone point me to a resource, perhaps a tutorial, on writing things without using the Companion code generator?

Answer (score 3):

The GNU Radio Companion (GRC) is just a design tool. It's a companion.

GNU Radio has tutorials that explain writing flow graphs in Python.

Go to https://tutorials.gnuradio.org and click on "Understanding a Flowgraph's Python Code".

Didactically, most of the things you need to learn are of the "what is the logic behind doing this DSP", which is really a math/signal processing thing, not just a Python coding excercise. Unless you've built similar signal processing flow systems before, I'd strongly discourage trying to do what you're intending to do. Get a VM in which GRC works  (see comment), and do the tutorials from start to finish in the specified order. Trying to learn GNU Radio, flowgraph-based DSP design AND doing all by hand instead of having a handy graphical design tool is a recipe for frustration.

Comment: Honestly, though. There seems to be a severe GTK bug on M1, maybe you just want to boot a quick linux x86 VM running ubuntu 22.04 and `sudo apt install gnuradio` there. It really just works.